# Laravel Blade: @endsection vs @stop

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

In Laravel Blade, we can basically do this:

```
@section('mysection')

@endsection


@section('mysection')

@stop
```

What is the difference between `@stop` and `@endsection`?

Comment: Both work `@endsection` and `@stop`. I find `@endsection` feels more intuitive. that's why i also use `@endsection` in laravel 8. Note: in the laravel 8 documentation you won't find anything more about `@stop.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `@endsection` was used in Laravel 3 and it was deprecated in Laravel 4

In the Laravel 4 to end a section you have to use `@stop`

You can refer the Changelog here
http://wiki.laravel.io/Changelog_%28Laravel_4%29#Blade_Templating

Comment: but still usable (even in the 5 version)

Comment: i don't think it's deprecated anymore, they even use it as an example in the currenet version docs. no notice of the @stop keyword http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade

Comment: @endsection isn't 'deprecated' anymore in Laravel 5.2, so this answer should be updated.

Comment: And the link is dead.

Comment: It is not deprecated. If you look at Laravel's official documentation, even in version 6.0 they are still introducing @endsection for the blade.

Answer (score 18):

Both `@endsection` and `@stop` works.

In Laravel 4 it seems that only `@stop` is supported [1](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#extending-blade). But from Laravel 5 onwards `@stop` is not even mention in the documentation [2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade).

So I would suggest to use **`@endsection`**.

See:

- [Laravel 4 Blade Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#extending-blade)
- [Laravel 5.7 Blade Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade) (current stable)

Comment: Because of the change in direction of Laravel, this is now the correct answer!

Answer (score 15):

#### Authoritative answer by Taylor Otwell

`@endsection` became `@stop` in L4, just as `@yieldSection` became `@show`.

[At github, Taylor Otwell said](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/978#issuecomment-16510172)

> **@stop** is just @endsection from L3.. **@show** is just @yieldSection