# Laravel: View not showing up html data

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')
@section('content')
<h1>Its working</h1>
@stop
```

As a result 'its working' is not appearing on the browser. blade is getting execution but not html.

Comment: what version you are using

Comment: Do you `@yield('content')` in your `layouts.dashboard` ?

Comment: please post the code of `layouts.dasbaord` you must be missing @show their i guess.

Comment: HI check this for best learn:
https://therichpost.com/laravel-blade-template-best-practices

Answer (score 2):

there might be a chance that you didn't write

`@yield('content')` in `layout.dashboard` blade template

or maybe you misspelled it. try to double check in spellings in `@yield('content')` and also `@section('content')`. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@endsection` instead of `@stop`

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')

@section('content')
    <h1>Its working</h1>
@endsection
```

Comment: Both works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21199412/laravel-blade-endsection-vs-stop

Answer (score 0):

@extends It allows you to include the content of the one file into another

The @section directive, as the name implies, defines a section of content

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')
@section('content')
    <h1>Its working</h1>
@endsection
```

Read more about @extends [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#extending-a-layout)

---

you can also use this way:

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')
@section('content')
    <h1>Its working</h1>
@stop
```

It's not deprecated, you can use either @stop or @endsection, both work fine. (I checked in Laravel5.7 and it's working)

Difference between @stop and @endsection you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21199412/laravel-blade-endsection-vs-stop/)

Answer (score 0):

To extend a blade in laravel, you have to tell the file that should be extended where you want the section to be. So your file to extend needs to have a `@yield('sectionName')` in order to extend the file correctly: So you need this filestructure:

**base.blade.php**

```
@yield('title')
<p>This is some sample text</p>
```

**part.blade.php**

```
@extends('base')
@section('title')
<h1>This is the title</h1>
@endsection
```

**The resulting file looks like this**

```
<h1>This is the title</h1>
<p>This is some sample text</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `@endsection` instead of `@stop`

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')
@section('content')
    <h1>Its working</h1>
@endsection
```

In blade file, multiple `@section` tags can be added that's why you have to add `@endsection`.